# Is $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ isomorphic to the localization of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ at the maximal ideal $(t)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

It seems to me that the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is isomorphic to the localization of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ at the maximal ideal $(t)$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does $C[[t]]$ denote the ring of Laurent series?

Comment: @stressedout I mean $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is the formal power series ring in one variable.

Comment: No. It is its completion for the $t$-adic topology.

Comment: @Bernard In that case, will $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ be finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$, the localization of $\mathbb{C][t]$ at $(t)$?

Comment: @stressedout: The ring of (formal) Laurent series is the field of fractions of $\mathbf C[[t]]$.

Comment: @Bernand Thanks. What does $\mathbf v$ denote there? I was thinking that maybe the ring of Laurent series could be viewed as the localization of polynomials at the multiplicative set $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots\}$.

Comment: @Ron: I don't think so: it would imply any formal power series is integral over $\mathbf C[t]_{(t)}$.

Comment: $\mathbf v$ was just a typo.. The localisation of polynomials at powers of the indeterminate defines the ring of *Laurent polynomials*.

Comment: @Bernard That makes sense. Silly me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. The ring $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ is naturally a subring of $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$, yet this inclusion is proper. For example one can solve $\sqrt{1-t}$ over $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ and there is no solution over $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ itself? or is it bigger?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ certainly is bigger, for example it contains $\frac{1}{t-1}\in \mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$

Comment: Sorry for asking dummy questions, I'm just interested in math. What does determine if a formal power series is in $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ or not?

Comment: @user881391 I am sorry but, $1/(t-1)$ is also an element of $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ (take the power series expansion). Moreover, by the universal property of inverse limit, there is a natural morphism from $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ to $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$.